# UBUNTU 20.04 I Installed on USB Does Not Boot Properly

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, bios

As I mentioned in the title, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 version on USB and use it via USB. But when I restart or shut down the computer, when I select Ubuntu after GRUB, I get the following error.
[image]
After this error, when I enter and exit the BIOS menu, it boots properly. But after every restart or shutdown, I have to do this. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Greetings. 
Did you create the recommended partitions on your pen drive before installing ubuntu? If yes, could you please share the detail.

Thanks

Mohammad

Comment: Firstly, thanks your comment Mohammed, After creating this title, I rewrote the ISO file to USB as "GPT". And I divided the disk I installed into 3 parts. These are 1GB EFI, 4GB SWAP, 30GB HOME and 30GB "/" directory. I made the separations carefully and accurately. After these steps, there were some improvements. Firstly,I no longer have to constantly enter and exit the BIOS.But when I login to other operating systems without USB, and then I want to plug the USB into the computer and enter Ubuntu, I have the same problem.

Comment: And in the BIOS Boot menu, it has to be 1st row USB Hard Disk and 2nd row HDD. If not, I continue to have the problem. But as I said, it is enough to enter and exit the BIOS once in these situations.In conclusion, I think the problem is mostly related to the BIOS I use.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer definitively, I'd like to know which software you used to image the disk. If you simply used something like DD, and didn't get a checksum of the disk afterwards, there's a good chance the image didn't write correctly. I'd personally recommend something like [balena etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) that checks the hash of a disk before it allows you to eject it. I'd also recommend you check the hashes provided with the image you downloaded against the downloaded ISO. If those two checks fail, you may want to [check your usb drive for errors and fix them](https://www.maketecheasier.com/repair-corrupted-usb-drive-linux/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jake,
In the comment below, I will explain the situation in detail. As a result of my tests, I realized that the problem is related to the BIOS I have and that I am doing the ISO writing process as "MBR".

Comment: Hey, @chap0, could you send over some screenshots of your BIOS? You may need to enable secure(UEFI) boot and disable legacy booting to get this to work

Comment: Hey @Jake, Shouldn't Secure Boot be turned off? I turned off Secure Boot and changed OS Support to UEFI. Because I did the installation as GPT and the systems installed on the computer were always installed UEFI.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to try re-installing with UEFI enabled? That would probably resolve and incompatibilities

Comment: The only problem I have is that the settings are reset when I start the computer without the USB where Ubuntu installed. So, when I want to open it another time with USB, I have to enter and exit the BIOS once. If I do not, after choosing Ubuntu on the GRUB screen, "You need to load to kernel first." I get this warning. As a result, I do not see this as a huge problem.

Comment: I'm quite stumped. I'm sorry but I don't think I know how to help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for all comment Jake. I think I don't want to deal with it any more. It is enough to use it this way.